# What test management tool to manage Cucumber tests?

Tags: test-management, tools

In my company we have our tests specified in Gherkin (Cucumber), and we use Jenkins to schedule the execution of these tests.

We have the need of a management tool, where we can associate the tests to the requirements and have the reports. Are there some tools that read the Cucumber feature files?

Thanks

Comment: user1553, I do not understand your goal.  Does the management tool need to interact with jenkins?  Should the report show the results of your tests, or should the report just show the relationship between requirements and Cucumber feature files?  Or do you consider the Cucumber feature files to be the requirements?

Comment: If I've understood right, you can use Cucumber to run your Gherkin tests. So I guess it's just a question of how you go about invoking Cucumber. If you've got your CI server working, it shouldn't be too hard to add a "build" step that will execute your Gherkin tests.

Answer (score 4):

I came across XRAY on Jira Cloud and i found its really usefull, I have started using in our company and replaced zephyr . Xray will give the opportunity to maintain both manual and automated test in one single interface. It support Rest api so you can import results from jenkins and update jira issues also.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.xpandit.plugins.xray/server/overview

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to associate specs with tests, then You're cuking it wrong.

If you are using cucumber right, the specs ARE the tests.

I'd suggest you get 'The Cucumber Book" from the Pragmatic Programmers.  Tons of good stuff in there about how to use the tool effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://relishapp.com (which I founded).

Comment: Can you please add some more information about the link. Link only answers are frowned upon here.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a ticket management system such as Trello, Jira, or Pivotal Tracker or TestLink.  I would look to use the same system that I am using for managing new features, tasks and bugs.

Answer (score 0):

With Test Collab, you can link test cases with their automated class methods. Take a look at this screencast: http://testcollab.com/blog/screencast-test-automation-with-test-collab/ It demonstrates integration of test cases with PHPUnit_Selenium package. Similarly cucumber can be integrated too.

We do not have automated scheduling feature yet - but you can do this:

Create test execution at Test Collab via API triggered by your Jenkins. Once test execution is assigned, Test Collab will automatically trigger your cucumber tests.

Disclaimer: I'm co-founder of Test Collab.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions

1. **Need for management tool where we can associate the tests to the requirements and have the reports.** You don't need any other management tools to associate the tests to requirements since that is done using cucumber feature files. For reports from Gherkin, you can use the cucumber-jenkins plugin on Jenkins, export you test results in JSON files after each test run and publish Cucumber reports as a post execution step.
2. **Tools that read the Cucumber feature files.** There are tools that read Cucumber files and allow you to easily share, manage and search your product's live documentation online from the feature files.

Example https://relishapp.com

Comment: This answer would be much more useful with examples of the tools and a short description of how to use them.

Comment: i will add detailed steps for both of these

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chuck, really you shouldn't be storing your feature files in any TCM program.

However, if you are writing acceptance tests in Gherkin format and the automating specific ones I've been using Testrail. It has a pretty good API and UI scripts (Im using one that does highlighting on the Gherkin keywords).

I then take some of those and create feature files out of the ones im going to automate (which I will then proceed to keep in our repo of choice).