# Test Management Tool for Cucumber

Tags: test-management, cucumber, test-report

I am investigating the use of Cucumber in my company, but I will need a good test management tool to store test results, and do reporting.

Can anyone recommend a test management tool that can work with Cucumber?

(Note that I have taken a look at [What test management tool to manage Cucumber tests?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2095/what-test-management-tool-to-manage-cucumber-tests). This was in 2012 and there is nothing suitable there that I can use, and I am hoping for an update on the info)

Comment: What do you expect from a test-management tool? What are your test-result goals, how do you want to report them?

Answer (score 2):

Cucumber is your test-management tool, not? The scenario's are the test-cases for the requirement.

The [the cucumber book](https://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) explains how you can structure your features in a logical way to use it as documentation.

I suggest you combine [cucumber-reporting](https://github.com/masterthought/cucumber-reporting) with [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) to run the cucumber steps and archive the results per build.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Reporting is taken care by Cucumber report but if you are looking for
>   something smooth like QC-QTP combo , you will not find it with cucumber .

***The max you will get is that the features which are run using cucumber are stored and tracked in Jira.***