# Test Management Tool for Cucumber part 2

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, cucumber

I saw there is already a question on this, as well as an answer in this link: [Test Management Tool for Cucumber](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/test-management-tool-for-cucumber)
But I have a doubt, as is suggested I used Jenkins and created a job to execute my Cucumber tests and get the corresponding report. But my question is....what if I want to execute some of the cucumber tests manually? where should I store those results and how? I know there are many TC management tools but it would be helpful to have one where you decide if you want to execute it manually or automatically so you maintain only one tool and not 2.
Does anyone know if there is something like that, that I can use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test Management Tool for Cucumber](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/test-management-tool-for-cucumber)

Answer (score 2):

I came across XRAY on Jira Cloud and i found its really usefull , i have started using in our company and relaced zephyr . Xray will give the opportunity to maintain both manual and automated test in one single interface. It support Rest api so you can import result from jenkins and update jira issues also.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.xpandit.plugins.xray/server/overview

Comment: Hi Lraghawan, I know you're well intentioned but I would not recommend copy/pasting an exact answer on multiple questions. You might get viewed as a spambot. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best solution but you can integrate your automated tests (cucumber) with some TC management like Testlink in a way that, after each job execution, cucumbers scenarios will be pushed to Testlink via Testlink API and will generate Manual scenarios there for you.
We implemented it in our project but I should say it is not the cleanest approach.

Comment: Is there any other test Management tool that could work? I saw a couple of plugins for Jira but most of them are not available for the Jira Cloud. Any one? Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

I think this tool "cucumbumbler" (it uses a tag driven mechanism to identify manually executed test cases from automatable ones) should be perfect fit for your scenario.

Also includes a pretty cool reporting feature/test suite (A book).

Refer to below wiki link:

https://github.com/TimWalker/cucumbumbler/wiki

Git repo:

https://github.com/TimWalker/cucumbumbler

Comment: Could it be integrated to any Test Management Tools?

Comment: No, cucumbumbler doesn't provide an integration to QC ALM or Jira, but since its an open source you can write a plugin for it (if need be).
cucumbumbler provides an option to store test scripts in "A Book" ( which is primary documentation and a living source of truth)
In addition to all that, I feel its an good idea to use Cucumber as your test management tool.

Answer (score 0):

> I know there are many TC management tools but it would be helpful to
>   have one where you decide if you want to execute it manually or
>   automatically so you maintain only one tool and not 2.

I've heard this problem before from many testers and teams. While we were developing Test Collab's automation feature - we wanted to solve it. It took a few iterations but we did solved it. How, you may ask? You define automation variables right where you define the test cases, so in a project, for example, you can have total 100 test cases, 20 of which are automated. Now from single app, you can trigger these automated cases or assign those 80 manual test cases to testers because of the common interface for triggering automated/manual tests. This really saves time when you are doing lot of testing on daily basis and also brings everything in one single app. If you would like to check out, I suggest you try our tool first: http://testcollab.com

Then jump to the automation settings: http://testcollab.com/blog/screencast-test-automation-with-test-collab/

(Disclaimer: I'm co-founder of Test Collab.)

Answer (score 0):

I came across Hiptest on another thread that says it supports JIRA Cloud. I have no experience of it though but the poster rated it highly.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/hiptest.jira-plugin/cloud/overview